# ProgressDialog не выполняется, как исправить?

Tags: java, android

Не знаю как исправить но мне кажется что в начале выполняется onCreate а потом только после него создаются граф интерфейсы. Мне надо чтобы ProgressDialog сразу появился до выполнении функции server.get_start(); и пропал после нее, но этого не происходит.

```
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vebor__server_ac);


    startDialog("Выбор сервера", "Пожалуйста подождите...");


    server.get_start();


    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, server.getServer());
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);

    unsetDialog();
}



ProgressDialog myDialog;
protected void startDialog(String name, String podname){
    myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, name, podname, true);
}

protected void unsetDialog(){
    myDialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Является ли **server.get_start()** асинхронной задачей?

Comment: " 
 
Является ли server.get_start() асинхронной задачей?" поясни

Comment: Наверняка же вы в сеть идёте в этом методе. А для этого нужно пользовать AsyncTask или Service или ещё что-то, выполняющееся вне основного потока приложения. Так ведь? Просто то, как вы сейчас делаете либо невозможно либо в корне неправильно в силу не понимания основ жизненного цикла активити.

Comment: Я пробовал делать в не основного потока, но там начинались проблемы что this не доступен, а я не знаю как ему передать this.

Comment: Вот пример: Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                myDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, name, podname, true);
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Вот додумал но вылетает приложение на строчке show.

Comment: myDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        myDialog.setTitle("Title");
        myDialog.setMessage("Message");
        
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                    myDialog.show();
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
        try {
            thread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

Comment: Здесь проблема в том, что нельзя вьюхи из не-UI потока трогать. Вынесите вашу задачу в AsyncTask. Это будет как раз то, что вам надо.

Comment: Хм ищю простой пример AsyncTask c ProgressDialog пока не нахожу.

Comment: Вот простейший пример: http://briandolhansky.com/blog/2013/7/11/snippets-android-async-progress

Answer (score 1):

Если ваша проблема сводится к тому, что вы не можете получить **Context** (а именно он скрывается под **this** в случае написания кода в теле класса активити), то вам просто надо его передать в метод нужный. Сделать это можно множеством способов. Например можно в onCreate активити переменной класса активити типа Context назначить собственно Context:

```
private Context ctx;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.ctx=this;
    //теперь вы можете использовать "ctx" вместо "this" когда вам нужен контекст активити.

}
```

Comment: Ну зачем же учить плохому? Копию this в активности потом будет только мешать. В вашем же примере был варинат с MyMainActivity.this

Comment: Я не претендую на то, что прав, но сам пользую такой способ в, например, методах анонимных классов (типа слушателей кликов). Мне он кажется (ИМХО) красивше, чем пользовать MyMainActivity.this. Тем более, что я часто передаю Context куда-нить в конструктор и у меня по всему проекту единая система обозначения контекста.